# Free Memory Occupied by Std List, Vector, Map etc

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

Coming from a C# background, I have only vaguest idea on memory management on C++-- all I know is that I would have to free the memory manually. As a result my C++ code is written in such a way that objects of the type `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map` are freely instantiated, used, but not freed.

I didn't realize this point until I am almost done with my programs, now my code is consisted of the following kinds of patterns:

```
struct Point_2
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct Point_3
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

list<list<Point_2>> Computation::ComputationJob
    (list<Point_3>pts3D, vector<Point_2>vectors)
{
    map<Point_2, double> pt2DMap=ConstructPointMap(pts3D);
    vector<Point_2> vectorList = ConstructVectors(vectors);
    list<list<Point_2>> faceList2D=ConstructPoints(vectorList , pt2DMap);
    return faceList2D;
}
```

My question is, must I free ***every.single.one*** of the list usage ( in the above example, this means that I would have to free `pt2DMap`, `vectorList` and `faceList2D`)? That would be very tedious! I might just as well rewrite my `Computation` class so that it is less prone to memory leak.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Actually it's better to use references in method parameters. Copying is not efficient.

Comment: @ssmir, old habits in C# die hard!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No: if objects are not allocated with `new`, they need not be freed/deleted explicitly. When they go out of scope, they are deallocated automatically. When that happens, the destructor is called, which should deallocate all objects that they refer to. (This is called [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization, or RAII](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), and standard classes such as `std::list` and `std::vector` follow this pattern.)

If you do use `new`, then you should either use a smart pointer (`scoped_ptr`) or explicitly call `delete`. The best place to call `delete` is in a destructor (for reasons of exception safety), though smart pointers should be preferred whenever possible.

Comment: @larsmans,  so you are saying that I don't have to deal with the deallocation of memory for `std::list` and all?

Comment: Due to all the copying, there are some situations where simple RAII can be a bit of a disaster when combined with the C++ containers.

Comment: Only if you, as T.E.D. says, use `new` in `class Point_2`, you need to worry about allocation and deallocation. The standard containers handle memory allocation internally. (Read about RAII, it's useful in avoiding the drudgeries of manual memory management.)

Comment: @T.E.D.: that's where smart pointers such as `shared_ptr` come in.

Comment: @Graviton - You don't. However, you do have to deal with the fact that map is liable to be making copies of the object you give it. If the default constructor and destructor for your object are complex, this may be a non-trivial issue for you.

Comment: @Graviton to repeat the most important part of the answer.  If you call new you must call delete.  The only time you need to care about explicitly cleaning up memory is when you explicitly allocate memory.  Now another thing to be aware of is that it causes errors to deallocate the same memory twice.

Comment: `If you do use new, then you should explicitly call delete. The best way to do so is in a destructor (for reasons of exception safety).` I strongly disagree with that. `If you do use new, put it into a smart pointer like boost::scoped_ptr` would be far better, and avoids all sorts of issues that can occur when using raw pointers, like deallocating the same thing twice like stonemetal mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

What I can say in general is that the C++ standard containers make copies of your object under the scenes. You have no control over that. What this means is that if construction of your objects (`Point_2` in your case) involves any resource allocations (eg: `new` or `malloc` calls), then you have to write custom versions of the copy constructors and destructors that make this behave sensibly when your map decides to copy `Point_2`s around. Usually this involves techniques like reference counting.

Many people find it much easier to just put pointers to complex object into standard containers, rather than the objects themselves.

If you don't do anything special in constructors or destructors for your objects (which now appears to be the case for you), the there's no problem whatsoever. Some containers (like maps) will be doing dynamic allocations under the scenes, but that is effectively invisible to you. **The containers worry about their resource allocations. You only have to worry about yours.**

Comment: question updated. Not too sure what you mean,  I don't need to use `new` or `malloc` to allocate memory for both `Point_2` and `Point_3`, as shown in the above code, so i guess that means that I don't need any custom code for memory management.

Comment: Agreed. With those (often called **POD** s or Plain Old Data types), you can use STL containers with abandon without having to worry about dynamic allocations.

Answer (score 0):

All stl containers clean up their contents automatically, all you must care is cleaning of data you allocate dynamically (i.e. the rule is: take care of the pointers).

For example, if you have `list<MyType>` - the list contains objects of some custom type inside - on a destruction it will call `~MyType()` which should take care of proper cleaning the object contents (I.e. if MyType has some pointers to allocated memory inside, you should delete them in the destructor).

On the other hand, if you start using `list<MyType*>` - the container does now how to clean this properly, it contains some scalar values (just like integers) and will delete just pointers themselves, without cleaning pointed content, so you need to clean this manually.

A really good advice (helped me a lot years ago :) ) when switching from Java/C# to C++ is to carefully trace each dynamic memory object lifecycle: a) where it gets created, b) where it gets used, c) where and when it gets deleted.
Make sure it is cleaned only once and does not get referenced after that!

Comment: Edited "std" to "stl", as STD has some other unfortunate connotations in English. Revert if you like. I do agree that if all std containers cleaned up their contents automatically, the world would be a much better place. :-)

Comment: Underrated comment is underrated